# Truncate multiple one line text elements

Tags: html, css

I want to truncate multiple text elements.

The text in the red and green box have both variable lenghts. The blue box with some UI-Elements has a fixed length of 200px.

If you resize the browser window, the blue box is shifted left and at **FIRST** the text in the green box should be truncated. If there isn't any more to truncate in the green box, then the text in the red box should be truncated.

I have tried it with `display:flex` but then the green box has some space on left to the red box, but the green box should be close to the red box - as shown in my snippet. **Annotation:** As explained above > the text in red/green box is variable > they havn't a fixed width.

(At the moment the blue box is shifted downside - I wasn't also able to fix this.)

```html
    <div style="display:table;width:100%; border:1px solid black;">
        <div style="float:left; white-space: nowrap;  overflow: hidden;  text-overflow: ellipsis;border:1px solid red;">
            Text with High Priority
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;border:1px solid green;">
            Text with Low Priority
        </div>
        <div style="float:right;width:200px;min-width:200px;border:1px solid blue;">
            <button type="submit" name="action" value="1">test</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with flexbox by giving the low priority element a big `flex-shrink` factor

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.high,
.low{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-width:20px;
}

.low {
  flex-shrink:9999;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.button {
  margin-left:auto;
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="high">
    Text with High Priority
  </div>
  <div class="low">
    Text with Low Priority
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="1">test</button>
  </div>
</div>
```